# discord.py bot is spamming, on the on_message event

Tags: discord, discord.py

There's an issue with discord.py.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != message.author:
        return
    else:
        if message == "Buck" or "buck":
           await message.channel.send("Yes, he's the Chairman of Dallas!")
```

It basically repeats to the infinity "yes he's the chairman of dallas" which can get me banned for api abuse and possibly make me fail a commission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An expression like this:

```py
if x == "foo" or "bar" or "baz":
```

Python is interpreting it like this:

```py
if (x == "foo") or ("bar") or ("baz"):
```

If the first expression `(x == "foo")` isn't true, the second `("bar")` will be, so this compound conditional always passes.

Try this instead:

```py
if x == "foo" or x == "bar" or x == "baz":
```

Or, even better:

```py
if x in ("foo", "bar", "baz"):
```

Also, you're comparing the whole `discord.Message` instance instead of just the content.

Fixing your code:

```py
if message.content in ("Buck", "buck"):
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
@client.event
  async def on_message(message):
       if message.author == bot.user:
           return 
       if message.content.lower() == "buck":
           await message.channel.send("Yes, he's the Chairman of Dallas!") 

`bot` here refers to your `discord.Bot` instance.
```